# How many rows can html table show in one page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have HTML table and I fetch the result from large MySQL database in it, these results can be thousands of records (rows).

My question is that will HTML table can handle with this situation? and will it expand to show all these rows in one page?

Comment: HTML should not have such a limitation (not with 1000s of recs definitely), but you may get a problem with downloading page performance, local performance (memory), even back end performance. If you do not have a specific reason to show everything in one page, consider solutions for pagination, filter, lazy load, etc.

Comment: The limit will be on your clients systems. Presuming you aren't appending all rows to a variable. You can test performance with something like: https://3v4l.org/nmY8a increase `$limit` to see how a row affects performance. Likely 5 cells will take 5* as many resources.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there are no limits on the number of `rows` you can print in an HTML `<table>` element.

However, just printing all that data in the page, is not a good User Experience practice (for most cases).

Another point to keep in mind is, if you have thousands of rows, your page may become slow to process all the data or even crash.

The two options you have to solve that are:

#### 01 - Limit the data that comes from the server

If you have control over the server (backend), you can limit the number of results that will return to the client (frontend).

Pros:

- More control over the data
- Faster loading times for your page

Cons:

- Your server becomes more complex, since it needs to handle the data limit (pagination)
- Any operation in the data (sorting, filtering, searching) needs to happen in the server, which may be a slow operation for the user

#### 02 - Limit the data using a library in the client-side

There are many options for that today. From pure Javascript to jQuery, React, etc. It all depends on the technology you are using, but a quick search on *"javascript table library"* will return you a lot of options.

You can also handle it yourself, but those libraries are usually optimized to handle big loads of data, by using *virtualization* and other techniques.

Pros:

- Operations are usually faster for the user
- More control on the client side (meaning more control for the user)

Cons:

- Initial loading time is usually slower (since you need to load the whole data)
- Possible dependency on a third-party library and its limitations